# BeautifulSoup cannot use if is None then continue statement to avoid 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable Type Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ticker='FAST'
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=nasdaq+%s+earnings+reaction+history&tbs=qdr:m"%(ticker)
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
# for searchs in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd'}):
cache = []
for searchs in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'kCrYT'}):
    if searchs.find('a')['href'] is None: continue
    cache.append(searchs.find('a')['href'])
    print(''.join(cache))
```

I wish to use the if continue statement to avoid the type error when .find('a')['href'] returns no result. However it does not do the job.  Could somebody point out a way to overcome it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Related: [Python: continue iteration of for loop on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293086/python-continue-iteration-of-for-loop-on-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what else you wanted to do with block if only after `href` then use `select` and specify that the parent class with child element with `href` attribute using descendant combinator

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ticker='FAST'
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=nasdaq+%s+earnings+reaction+history&tbs=qdr:m"%(ticker)
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
cache = [searchs['href'] for searchs in soup.select('div.kCrYT [href]')]
print(''.join(cache))
```

Comment: really nice solution!  I want to collect the search result and visit the valid urls, the soup.select() avoids if...continue and try...except statement altogether, really nice and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to escape from `TypeError`.

```py
try:
    cache.append(searchs.find('a')['href'])
except TypeError:
    continue
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know how to use try + except to handle the error. What I wish to figure out is the problem associated with the if continue statement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to put so much in one line:

```
...
for searchs in soup.find_all('div'):
    tag = searchs.find('a')
    #print(searchs)
    if not tag:
        continue
    try:
        h = tag['href']
    except KeyError as e:
        continue
    print(h)
```

Comment: Yes, the problem lies exactly in the searchs.find('a') is None case for which referring to its field 'href' produces the type error!